# Minimum distance between elements in two logical vectors

Tags: r

I have two logical vectors `x` and `y` and weighted values, `z` corresponding to each index.  For column `x` values that are `TRUE` I'd like to find the nearest `y` column index that is also `TRUE`.  Then grab the `sum` of `z` between min{`x_i`, `y_i`}.  If there are two min{`x_i`, `y_i`} then the smaller `sum` of `z` is used.

```
       x     y          z
1  FALSE  TRUE 0.05647057
2  FALSE FALSE 0.09577802
3   TRUE FALSE 0.04150954
4  FALSE FALSE 0.07242995
5  FALSE  TRUE 0.06220041
6  FALSE FALSE 0.01861535
7  FALSE FALSE 0.05056971
8   TRUE FALSE 0.07726933
9  FALSE  TRUE 0.04669694
10  TRUE  TRUE 0.02312497
```

There are 3 `x` values that are `TRUE` so we'll call them {`x_1`, `x_2`,  `x_3`}.  Here I demonstrate the summing of the minimum indexes between each `x_i` and it's nearest `y_i` neighbor.  What is the most efficient base R way to accomplish this.  I have a method at the end that utilizes 2 `lapply` telling me it's probably not efficient.  I don't have a math background and usually there's some algebraic way to accomplish these sorts of tasks that is vectorized over the brute computational power.

```
## x_1
sum(z[3:5]) ## This one is smaller so use it
sum(z[1:3])

## x_2
sum(z[8:9])

## x_3
sum(z[10])

c(sum(z[3:5]), sum(z[8:9]), sum(z[10]))
[1] 0.17613990 0.12396627 0.02312497
```

**MWE**:

```
x <- y <- rep(FALSE, 10)
x[c(3, 8, 10)] <- TRUE
y[c(1, 5, 9, 10)] <- TRUE
set.seed(15)
z <- rnorm(10, .5, .25)/10
data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z)
```

Here is an approach that is less than optimal:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z)
sapply(which(dat[, "x"]), function(x) {
    ylocs <- which(dat[, "y"])
    dists <- abs(x - ylocs)
    min.ylocs <- ylocs[min(dists) == dists]
    min(sapply(min.ylocs, function(y, x2 = x) {
        sum(dat[, "z"][x2:y])
    }))
})

## [1] 0.17613990 0.12396627 0.02312497
```

I'd prefer to keep the solution within base.

Comment: are the values in `z` always non-negative?

Comment: Yes they are non negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses no loops or apply functions.  We use `na.locf` from zoo to move the index of the last TRUE `y` up giving `fwd` and the next TRUE `y` back giving `bck`. Finally we determine which of the two corresponding sums is greater.   This depends on `na.locf` in the zoo package but at the end we 
extract the core code from zoo to avoid the dependence:

```
library(zoo) # na.locf

x <- dat$x
y <- dat$y
z <- dat$z

yy <- ifelse(y, TRUE, NA) * seq_along(y)
fwd <- na.locf(yy, fromLast = FALSE)[x]
bck <- na.locf(yy, fromLast = TRUE)[x]

cs <- cumsum(z)
pmin(cs[x] - cs[fwd] + z[fwd], cs[bck] - cs[x] + z[x])
```

The last line gives:

```
[1] 0.17613990 0.12396627 0.02312497
```

Here is a mini version of `na.locf`.  The library call above could be replaced with this.

```
# code extracted from zoo package
na.locf <- function(x, fromLast = FALSE) {
   L <- !is.na(x)
   if (fromLast) rev(c(NA, rev(which(L)))[cumsum(rev(L)) + 1])
   else c(NA, which(L))[cumsum(L)+1L]
}
```

REVISED:  some improvements.

Comment: Thank you that is indeed faster