# Fast minimum distance (interval) between elements of 2 logical vectors (take 2)

Tags: r, performance, vector

I asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493662/minimum-distance-between-elements-in-two-logical-vectors) but realized I was burning too much time calculating this complex measure (And the goal is to use with a randomization test so speed is an issue).  So I've decided to throw out the weighting and just use the minimum distance between two measures.  So here I have 2 vectors (in a data frame for demo purposes but in reality they are two vectors.

```
       x     y
1  FALSE  TRUE
2  FALSE FALSE
3   TRUE FALSE
4  FALSE FALSE
5  FALSE  TRUE
6  FALSE FALSE
7  FALSE FALSE
8   TRUE FALSE
9  FALSE  TRUE
10  TRUE  TRUE
11 FALSE FALSE
12 FALSE FALSE
13 FALSE FALSE
14 FALSE  TRUE
15  TRUE FALSE
16 FALSE FALSE
17  TRUE  TRUE
18 FALSE  TRUE
19 FALSE FALSE
20 FALSE  TRUE
21 FALSE FALSE
22 FALSE FALSE
23 FALSE FALSE
24 FALSE FALSE
25  TRUE FALSE
```

Here I have some code worked out to find the minimal distance but I need more speed (removal of unnecessary calls and better vectorization).  Maybe I can't go any faster in base R.

```
## MWE EXAMPLE: THE DATA
x <- y <- rep(FALSE, 25)
x[c(3, 8, 10, 15, 17, 25)] <- TRUE
y[c(1, 5, 9, 10, 14, 17, 18, 20)] <- TRUE

## Code to Find Distances
xw <- which(x)
yw <- which(y)

min_dist <- function(xw, yw) {
    unlist(lapply(xw, function(x) {
        min(abs(x - yw))
    }))
}

min_dist(xw, yw)
```

Is there any way to improve performance in base R?  Using `dplyr` or `data.table`?

My vectors are much longer (10,000 + elements).

**Edit** per flodel's benching.  flodel there's an issue I had anticipated in my MWE and I'm not sure how to fix it either.  The problem arises if any x position is less than the minimum y position.

```
x <- y <- rep(FALSE, 25)
x[c(3, 8, 9, 15, 17, 25)] <- TRUE
y[c(5, 9, 10, 13, 15, 17, 19)] <- TRUE


xw <- which(x)
yw <- which(y)

flodel <- function(xw, yw) {
   i <- findInterval(xw, yw)
   pmin(xw - yw[i], yw[i+1L] - xw, na.rm = TRUE)
}

flodel(xw, yw)

## [1] -2 -1 -6 -2 -2 20
## Warning message:
## In xw - yw[i] :
##   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
flodel <- function(x, y) {
  xw <- which(x)
  yw <- which(y)
  i <- findInterval(xw, yw, all.inside = TRUE)
  pmin(abs(xw - yw[i]), abs(xw - yw[i+1L]), na.rm = TRUE)
}

GG1 <- function(x, y) {
  require(zoo)
  yy <- ifelse(y, TRUE, NA) * seq_along(y)
  fwd <- na.locf(yy, fromLast = FALSE)[x]
  bck <- na.locf(yy, fromLast = TRUE)[x]
  wx <- which(x)
  pmin(wx - fwd, bck - wx, na.rm = TRUE)
}

GG2 <- function(x, y) {
  require(data.table)
  dtx <- data.table(x = which(x))
  dty <- data.table(y = which(y), key = "y")
  dty[dtx, abs(x - y), roll = "nearest"] 
}
```

Sample data:

```
x <- y <- rep(FALSE, 25)
x[c(3, 8, 10, 15, 17, 25)] <- TRUE
y[c(1, 5, 9, 10, 14, 17, 18, 20)] <- TRUE

X <- rep(x, 100)
Y <- rep(y, 100)
```

Unit test:

```
identical(flodel(X, Y), GG1(X, Y))
# [1] TRUE
```

Benchmarks:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(flodel(X,Y), GG1(X,Y), GG2(X,Y))
# Unit: microseconds
#          expr       min         lq     median        uq        max neval
#  flodel(X, Y)   115.546   131.8085   168.2705   189.069   1980.316   100
#     GG1(X, Y)  2568.045  2828.4155  3009.2920  3376.742  63870.137   100
#     GG2(X, Y) 22210.708 22977.7340 24695.7225 28249.410 172074.881   100
```

[Edit by Matt Dowle] 24695 microseconds = 0.024 seconds. Inferences made on microbenchmarks with tiny data rarely hold on meaningful data sizes.

[Edit by flodel] My vectors had length 2500 which was rather meaningful given Tyler's statement (10k), but fine, let's try with vectors of length 2.5e7. I hope you will forgive me for using `system.time` given the circumstances:

```
X <- rep(x, 1e6)
Y <- rep(y, 1e6)
system.time(flodel(X,Y))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.694   0.205   0.899 
system.time(GG1(X,Y))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  31.250  16.496 112.967 
system.time(GG2(X,Y))
# Error in `[.data.table`(dty, dtx, abs(x - y), roll = "nearest") : 
#   negative length vectors are not allowed
```

---

[Edit from Arun] - Benchmark for 2.5e7 using 1.8.11:
[Edit 2 from Arun] - Updating timings after Matt's recent *faster* binary search/merge

```
require(data.table)
arun <- function(x, y) {
    dtx <- data.table(x=which(x))
    setattr(dtx, 'sorted', 'x')
    dty <- data.table(y=which(y))
    setattr(dty, 'sorted', 'y')
    dty[, y1 := y]
    dty[dtx, roll="nearest"][, abs(y-y1)]
}

# minimum of three consecutive runs
system.time(ans1 <- arun(X,Y))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.036   0.138   1.192 

# minimum of three consecutive runs
system.time(ans2 <- flodel(X,Y))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.983   0.197   1.221 

identical(ans1, ans2) # [1] TRUE
```

Comment: there's an issue that the MWE doesn't account for.  I put the edit in my solution but your approach is so much faster I don't want to give up on it.

Comment: I think I fixed it, give it a try.

Comment: Yes indeed.  Thank you.  I also get what `all.inside = TRUE` does now too.  Thanks for introducing me to a new function.

Comment: @Tyler Rinker, Can you post the corresponding times with the 10,000 size data set?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck yes but it will be a couple of days until I can get to it and benchmark this.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I've been attempting to benchmark this, but once the size of the data grows, the solutions no longer offer the same value.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two solutions.  Neither use a loop nor an apply function.

**1)** The first is the same as the solution I posted to your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493662/minimum-distance-between-elements-in-two-logical-vectors) if `z` is 1 except the simplified assumptions here allow us to shorten it somewhat and we have reduced the answer by 1 relative to that one.

```
library(zoo)

yy <- ifelse(y, TRUE, NA) * seq_along(y)
fwd <- na.locf(yy, fromLast = FALSE)[x]
bck <- na.locf(yy, fromLast = TRUE)[x]
wx <- which(x)
pmin(wx - fwd, bck - wx, na.rm = TRUE)
```

**2)** The second is a data.table solution.  data.table can take a `roll="nearest"` argument which seems just what you need:

```
library(data.table)

dtx <- data.table(x = which(x))
dty <- data.table(y = which(y), key = "y")
dty[dtx, abs(x - y), roll = "nearest"]
```

I am not sure if it matters but I am using data.table version 1.8.11 (the CRAN version is currently 1.8.10).