# Minimum distance between two elements in same vector (r)

Tags: r, vector, sequence, data.table, grepl

I have a question which is similar to this one -  [Fast minimum distance (interval) between elements of 2 logical vectors (take 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499742/fast-minimum-distance-interval-between-elements-of-2-logical-vectors-take-2)   but it has some important differences.

Say I have a vector:

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "D", "A", "B", "A")
```

What I would like to do is:

For every element, calculate the minimum distance between it and the next element of each different type in the forward direction only.  If for any element, no element of a particular type occurs in the forward direction then a 0 should be returned.   The returned data will look like this:

Desired Output Table-

```
N  x  A  B  C  D
1  A  3  1  2  4
2  B  2  6  1  3
3  C  1  5  0  2
4  A  3  4  0  1
5  D  2  3  0  1
6  D  1  2  0  0
7  A  2  1  0  0
8  B  1  0  0  0
9  A  0  0  0  0
```

The first column/var simply refers to the element order.  The second col/var is the element at that position.   Then there are four cols/vars - each one being a unique element that occurs in the vector.

The numbers in each of these four cols/vars are the minimum distance from that row's element to the next occurring element of each type in the FORWARD direction only.  If a '0' is entered, that means that that element does not occur after that row's element in the vector.

How to achieve this?

My first thought was to try and mimic some aspects of the question above.  To that end, I used a grepl function to turn the vector into four separate logical vectors indicating the presence/absence of each element.

```
xA<-grepl("A", x) #  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
xB<-grepl("B", x) #  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
xC<-grepl("B", x) #  FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
xD<-grepl("D", x) #  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I then tried the "Flodel" function and the second function provided by GG using library(data.table).

For example, to compute the minimum distances from all "As" to a "D":

```
flodel <- function(x, y) {
  xw <- which(x)
  yw <- which(y)
  i <- findInterval(xw, yw, all.inside = TRUE)
  pmin(abs(xw - yw[i]), abs(xw - yw[i+1L]), na.rm = TRUE)
}
flodel(xA,xD)

> [1] 4 1 1 3




#GG's data.table option
wxA <- data.table(x = which(xA))
wxD <- data.table(y = which(xD), key = "y")
wxD[wxA, abs(x - y), roll = "nearest"] 

#   y V1
#1: 1  4
#2: 4  1
#3: 7  1
#4: 9  3
```

Both of these options find the minimum distance for all A's to a D.  However, it is in ANY direction, not the FORWARD direction only.    GG's data.table option is on the surface more attractive to me as it returns data showing the position of each element (the 'y' column of the output) which would make it easy to package into a nice summary table (such as my desired output table above).

I have tried to work out alternative ways of using the 'roll' argument in data.table, but I don't seem to manage this issue.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way that seems valid:

```
levs = sort(unique(x))
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(seq_along(x),
               function(n) 
                  match(levs, x[-seq_len(n)], 0)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    3    1    2    4
# [2,]    2    6    1    3
# [3,]    1    5    0    2
# [4,]    3    4    0    1
# [5,]    2    3    0    1
# [6,]    1    2    0    0
# [7,]    2    1    0    0
# [8,]    1    0    0    0
# [9,]    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure how efficient this is, but it seems to work. How about

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "D", "A", "B", "A")

#find indexes for each value
locations<-split(seq_along(x), x)

#for each index, find the distance from the next highest 
# index in the locations list
t(sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) sapply(locations, function(l) 
    if(length(z<-l[l>i])>0) z[1]-i else 0)))
```

This will return

```
      A B C D
 [1,] 3 1 2 4
 [2,] 2 6 1 3
 [3,] 1 5 0 2
 [4,] 3 4 0 1
 [5,] 2 3 0 1
 [6,] 1 2 0 0
 [7,] 2 1 0 0
 [8,] 1 0 0 0
 [9,] 0 0 0 0
```